# create vuex action to get the merged response from two api service - vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am making two apis calls for creating the category wise discount. Here is the services

**1. Api is for Categories name(api/categories)**

**// response payload**

```
    [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "Vegetables"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "Foods"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "Clothing"
    },
]
```

**service**

```
    export async function  getCategories() {
    const resp = await http.get('/categories');
    return resp.data;
}
```

**2. api is for discount details(api/categories/{product_id}/discount)**

**// response payload**

```
 [
    {
        "category_id": 2,
        "discount": 20
    },
    {
        "category_id": 3,
        "discount": 40
    },
    {
        "category_id": 1,
        "discount": 30
    }
   ]
```

**service**

```
export async function  getCategoryDiscount(id) {
const resp = await http.get(`/categories/${id}/discount');
return resp.data;
```

}

Now, i am calling this into vuex actions and want to merge these two into one state.

**Like state will be**

```
Categories: [{ id: 1, category: "vegetables", discount: 30},{...}]
```

****Vuex action** (as muka suggested)**

```
    async fetchCategoriesWithDiscount({commit,state}) {
     
    const productId = state.products.pros.key_details.product_id;
   const catResponse = await service.getCategories();
   const disResponse = await service.getCategoryDiscount(productId);
   console.log(catResponse,disResponse); // getting data correctly
   const allResponse = 
      Promise.all([catResponse,disResponse]).then(async(result)=> {
           const categories = await result[0].json(); // error is coming here
           const discount = await result[1].json();
           commit('updatedFetchCategories',{
              categories,
              discount
           });
       });
     console.log(allResponse);
   }

}
```

How to configure action to make the Category state with discount? I am getting error **"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result[0].json is not a function"**

Comment: The problem is that you mix-n-match `async` & `Promise`: they do not work together in the way you put them together. E.g. loog at what the `getCategories()` function returns - is it a `Promise` or is it real data? If it's a `Promise`, then you can put it in the `Promise.all`, if it's data, then you cannot. Then, `resp.data.json()` is not supposed to exist (most of the time). `.json()` is a method of `fetch()`. If you don't use `fetch()`, then it's not there. You have to customise the function in `Promise.all` to fit the data YOU are handling. My snippet was only an example.

Comment: Yes understood the point .I am getting the data not promise ... i am thinking how to add two response data into one ....

Comment: Yes i have changed that too.... It is working now.

Comment: Glad to hear that it’s working now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do this, depending on your preferences. If you really want to update the state only if all data has arrived, I suggest that you use a `Promise.all` approach (more on [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)):

```js
const initialState = () => ({
  postsWithComment: [],
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: initialState(),
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_POST(state, {
      post,
      comments
    }) {
      state.postsWithComment.push({
        ...post,
        comments,
      })
    },
  },
  actions: {
    fetchPostsAndComments({
      commit
    }) {
      const postResponse = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      const commentResponse = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments')

      // Promise.all in the action:
      const response = Promise.all([postResponse, commentResponse])
        .then(async(results) => {
          const {
            id,
            title
          } = await results[0].json()
          const comments = await results[1].json()
          commit("UPDATE_POST", {
            post: {
              id,
              title
            },
            comments
          })
        })
        // add a catch here, so you catch
        // the error of the fetches
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err)
        })
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  methods: {
    getPostsWithComments() {
      this.$store.dispatch("fetchPostsAndComments")
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="getPostsWithComments">GET DATA</button>
      <hr>
      {{ $store.state.postsWithComment }}
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response .... i am getting error ."Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result[0].json is not a function". Promise is also pending.

Comment: I have updated my question with your suggestion but i am getting not function error

Comment: @user7411584 then there's some other error in your code. You can see that the snippet works correctly. I edited the code, so now it has a `catch()` branch, so it tries to give error handling. Also, you are not using `fetch()` in your code, but `http.get`. `fetch()` returns a `Promise`, while `http.get` does not. You have to rework your "services" so they can be used with a `Promise.all`.